# How to convert strings from "GBK" to "UTF-8" in C#?

Tags: c#, email

I come up against problem when I develop my email client.I find the name of the email attachment in Chinese is messy code when I send an email with attachment which name include Chinese from my app to the email server and get if back from the server.But it is right at the email server.In addition,when I send an email with attachment which name include Chinese from the other client,it's all Ok. Thank you for all!

Comment: I'll suggest to check your email sending related library classes, if there are anything relative to Encoding, and play with it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it's looks normal on the email server which email I send from my client.

Comment: Then check classes to get email back.

Comment: But when I send an email from the other client, I get the email normaly. what happened？

Comment: I don't know what happened. But did you check?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean the string is stored in a byte array?

```
        string strSource = "abcdefg";
        byte[] array2=Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetBytes(strSource);

        //get string from gbk
        string str = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetString(array2);

        //convert string to utf-8
        byte[] array3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

=================answer is edited below, 2016.08.01=============

You should read the chinese name of the attach with gbk,  then you forword the email content to other place use utf-8 or gbk. 
you could have a try and test.